# AS3 change bitmap color to black color

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, bitmap, pixel

I have a image of the Bitmap class.
How I can change it's color to the black (color of all pixels except alpha)?

Answer (score 1):

I understand how to do it.

```
yourBitmap.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0, 0, 0, 1);
```